# passing a 2d-array to a function in c language, what is the difference between int* b[4] and int b[][4]?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory

I am trying to shift the rows of a 2-dimensional array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void shift_to_left(int* b[4], int* new_col){
  for(size_t i=0; i<1; i++)
    memcpy(*(b+i+1), *(b+i), sizeof(int)*4);
  memcpy(*(b+1), new_col, sizeof(int)*4);
}

int main(){
  int a[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  int b[2][4] = {{7, 8, 4, 5}, {8, 9, 5, 1}};

  printf("Before: \n");
  for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
      printf("%d ", b[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }

  shift_to_left(b, a);

  printf("After: \n");
  for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
      printf("%d ", b[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

I am getting a warning that tells me  that the function `shift_to_left()` was expecting a double pointer but was given an array:

```
array_to_pointer.c: In function ‘main’:
array_to_pointer.c:38:17: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘shift_to_left’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   shift_to_left(b, a);
                 ^
array_to_pointer.c:20:6: note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[4]’
 void shift_to_left(int* b[4], int* new_col)
```

When I ignore the warning and run the code, I get a segmentation fault:

```
Before: 
7 8 4 5 
8 9 5 1 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The segmentation fault goes away when I change the prototype of the function from `void shift_to_left(int* b[4], int* new_col)` to `void shift_to_left(int b[][4], int* new_col)`:

```
Before: 
7 8 4 5 
8 9 5 1 
After: 
7 8 4 5 
1 2 3 4
```

But in both cases, `memcpy(*(b+i+1), *(b+i), sizeof(int)*4);` does not work (the first row of array b stays the same).

**What's the difference between passing an array as `int* b[4]` and passing it as `int b[][4]`?**

**What's wrong with memcpy in this case?**

Comment: 'int b[][4]' is the same as 'int (*b)[4]' in this context

Comment: You've just discovered why it's almost always better to use 1D arrays and emulate 2D than to actually use 2D arrays or arrays of arrays. You can copy a 1D array in one shot, it's super easy. No loops needed.

Comment: Tip: Instead of `*(x+n)` do `x[n]`. The syntax is a lot tidier and it makes more sense to anyone familiar with C pointers and how they can work like arrays.

Comment: @tstanisl putting the parenthesis around  *b solves the issue!  int* b[4] is one thing, int (*b)[4] is another thing. What's with memcpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int* b[4]` is an array of 4 `int` pointers. `int (*b)[4]` is a pointer to an array of sets of 4 ints, as is `int b[][4]`.

In effect the same memory is interpreted one of two ways:

```
// int* b[4] (4x 64-bit pointers)
[aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccccdddddddd]
 ^ int* |^ int* |^ int* |^ int*

// int (*b)[4] (Nx 4x int)
[1111222233334444111122223333444411112222333344441111222233334444...]
 ^ int[4]       |^ int[4]       |^ int[4]       |^ int[4]
```

Treating an `int[4]` as a pointer is going to lead to an immediate segmentation fault when de-referenced. That's not a valid pointer.

If you turn on warnings (`-Wall` on many compilers) you'll get a message like this alerting you to the problem:

```
24d.c:21:17: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int [2][4]' to parameter of type 'int **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  shift_to_left(b, a);
```

If you're ever confused, which C tries its best to do, use a decoder like [cdecl](https://cdecl.org).